# Custom MarkerStyles possible in Microsoft Chart Controls?

Tags: c#, .net, charts, data-visualization, microsoft-chart-controls

I'm using [Microsoft Chart Controls](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart) (4.0), and have a line chart with several marker types. So much so, that I'm running out of markertypes. The defaults (square, triangle, circle, etc.) are insufficient.

Is it possible to add custom marker type images? For instance, I need a triangle pointed in the opposite direction.

Comment: What is the exact product name? For example, is it *Dundas Chart* or *Microsoft Chart Controls*?

Comment: Product name is "Microsoft Charts Controls" http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart

Answer (score 8):

You can create a opposite direction triangle image and set the marker image as

```
// Set an image marker for the third data point in series
Chart1.Series["Default"].Points[2].MarkerImage = "MyReverseTriangleImage.bmp";
Chart1.Series["Default"].Points[2].MarkerImageTransparentColor = Color.White;
```

Comment: Is this going to have any significant performance degridation?  My chart has upwards of hundreds of thousands of points.

Comment: In my opinion that depends on your marker image size. To be sure this won't cause any performance issues, a performance test could be run with your custom image and compare to a baseline test which uses one of the default images.

Comment: It is better to load the imges into the Chart.Images collection of NamedImages. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34487165/net-charting-legend-marker-size/34496091?s=4|0.1173#34496091) for an example!